# IText Paragraph preposition line breaks

Tags: itext

When creating long Paragraph with ALIGN_JUSTIFIED mine text has some "language grammar volations" which are very annoying for mine customer. Such volations occurs when line ends on single character like: 'o', 'i', etc. They are called preposition I guess. Those characters should be moved to next line and next line should start from them. The problem is I do not know if they occurs on the end or in the middle. Maybe someone will give me hint how to solve this ?

Please imagine that those two below examples are justified but they have line breaks in different place.

NOT OK:

**Demonstracja problemu z**

**bekartami**

OK (desired):

**Demonstracja problemu**

**z bekartami**

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved by using a non-breaking space.

Instead of using a `String` "z bekartami", you should use a `String` "z/u00a0bekartami".

This will solve your problem.